# Convert to JSON Array, not regular object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I have used this utility http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm to format tables of data.  It has the wonderful option of allowing you to convert to JSON or to a JSON Array.  That JSON Array is what I want.  When I use utilities like JSON.Net to serialize, they give me the standard JSON format.  I don't want that - I just want arrays, so I can basically reproduce a table layout in my javascript.

Here is sample table data structure

```
column1 column2 column3
c1r1    c2r1    c3r1
c1r2    c2r2    c3r2
c1r3    c2r3    c3r3
```

I want it to look like this when serialized:

```
[[c1r1,c2r1,c3r1],
 [c1r2,c2r2,c3r2],
 [c1r3,c2r3,c3r3]]
```

But the standard serialization method with a utility like JSON.net would be

```
[
  {
    column1:c1r1,
    column2:c2r1,
    column3:c3r1
  },
  {
    column1:c1r2,
    column2:c2r2,
    column3:c3r2
  },
  {
    column1:c1r3,
    column2:c2r3,
    column3:c3r3
  }
]
```

My question is, does anyone know of a way of stripping out column names and just making it like the simple 2d array I have shown?

Data structure is an `IEnumerable` taken directly from a sql command `db.Query("SELECT * FROM my_table")`.

Note: I want to have a generic function that can do this - I know how to do this for just one thing, but the project I'm working on needs it done for many in the same way.  I tried to write my own method to do it, but it didn't work because of limitations that c# has.

```
    public static string fromListToJSONArray(IEnumerable<Object> listToUse, string[] fieldNames)
    {
        string JSONString = "[";
        foreach (var item in listToUse)
        {
            JSONString += item[fieldName[0]]; //This is the line you can't do in c#!!  Don't know how to go around this.
        }
        JSONString += "]";
        return JSONString;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you think C# can't do? Do you get a compiler error? Tell us which error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: in javascript if you have a variable spaceship you can access property "x" like this spaceship.x or spaceship["x"]  in c# spaceship["x"] doesn't work - I tried the enumeration, but got an error that there was a nil value.

Comment: In C#, you can do this, and much more, using _Reflection_. You can certainly process all the properties of an arbitrary object. It just doesn't use the same syntax as JavaScript.

Comment: I tried that and I'm having trouble. `JSONString += item.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(item, null);` where `item` is a line in an `IEnumerable<Object>` Throws a null reference exception.  Do you know what that would be about?  the item variable is not null in the debugger.  This is really the best solution for me, I think, but I just can't make it work.

Comment: NullReferenceException means something is `null`. Check to see if `item.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName)` is null.

Comment: Hallelujah, that fixed it!  I found that the issue what this - I was passing in IEnumerable<object> when I should have been using IEnumerable<dynamic>.  It turns out that it actually returns what I wanted as an array if there is only value (all I have tested so far).  Many thanks for your help today.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - IEnumerable type needed to be "dynamic".  From there it is pretty simple

```
public static string fromListToJSONArray(IEnumerable<dynamic> listToUse)
    {
        string JSONString = "[";
        foreach (var item in listToUse)
        {
            if(isFirst == false)
                JSONString += ",";
            else
                isFirst = false;
            JSONString += "\"" + item[0] + "\"";
        }
        JSONString += "]";
        return JSONString;
        JSONString += "]";
        return JSONString;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to output is an array of arrays.  Starting with an enumerable or records (in your case it looks like it has columns called column1, column2, column3).

If the query will produce a know result set you can simple convert each row to an array before converting to JSON.

```
var qry = /*Enumerable of some database query*/
return from rec in wry
    select new string[] 
    {
      rec.column1, 
      rec.column2, 
      rec.column3
    };
```

Comment: If you want it to be generic, then you will need to use reflection to grab each property on the rec object, or use a data adapter to fill a DataTable (with DataAdapter or Data Reader you can retrieve column elements).

Comment: Thanks bigtlb, I'll look into those

Comment: I would go for [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx), unless you have a need to know the column names.  The columns are just a 0 based array.  And you can try to read them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491119/returning-json-results-without-property-names).

You'll have to assemble the array manually from the json.